WHITELISTING FUNCTION
I am thinking of methods to write a whitelist functions on a token. Is there a more efficient way to do this, as I want only specific wallets to be able to buy/send/transfer my tokens.

For that you can for example use the transfer hook extension of the token extension program (aka token 2022)
Its not an easy task though.
Here is a repository with a transfer hook whitelist example:
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/tokens/token-2022/transfer-hook/anchor/TransferHookWhitelist
And a video guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsduWRtT3r8&t=1053s&ab_channel=Solana
And the transfer hook guide:
https://solana.com/de/developers/guides/token-extensions/transfer-hook

thanks, let me have a deep dive.

What is the max size this transfer hook whitelist can store??
